# Xcode 11 constantly crashing after installing development provisioning profile

Tags: xcode, crash, profile, provisioning

I am trying to install provisioning profile but after adding my app is getting crash constantly.
please help
thank you

Comment: include a screenshot or exact error message with your question. It will be helpful to understand the exact root cause of your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do the following steps 
1. Close 11
2. Open Xcode 10
3. Install provisioning profiles
4. Open Xcode 11
5. Resolved